# How to create alarm for TargetResponseTime taking more the 30s for period of 5minutes

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-application-load-balancer, cloudwatch-alarms

I want to trigger an alarm when 30% of requests take more than 10s TargetResponseTime within a period of 5minutes in AWS cloud watch

Answer (score 0):

Check available statistics https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Statistics-definitions.html

Percentile rank (PR) should work in your case.
try with PR(10:300) and set threshold to 30%